# Pandas pivoting/stacking/reshaping from string in rows

Tags: pandas

Accepted answer from Sammy as it did solve the original post. Editing to include further complexity when using the solutions, some of the values themselves has spaces in them and so the regex breaks these as well. Including example change in key1=value 11.

This data seem designed to be analytics unfriendly.

I would like to convert a dataset in the form of:

```
pd.Series(["key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3", "key1=value 11 key2=value22 key3=value33", "key1=value111,key2=value222,key3=value333"])

#0          key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3
#1       key1=value 11 key2=value22 key3=value33
#2    key1=value111,key2=value222,key3=value333
#dtype: object
```

With the expected output:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"key1":["value1", "value 11", "value111"], "key2":["value2", "value22", "value222"], "key3":["value3", "value33", "value333"]})

#       key1      key2      key3
#0    value1    value2    value3
#1   value 11   value22   value33
#2  value111  value222  value333
```

The challenge of course is that both the variable names and values have to be parsed from the string.  I would also like to keep the index unchanged.

Comment: In this sample Series, some key-value pairs are delimited by space (index 0 and 1) and others by comma (index 2). Is that true in the real data or just a typo here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the entire transformation with python, which should be faster and easier. Given an input Series `s`:

```py
import re 
pd.DataFrame([dict(e.split('=') for e in re.split("[\s,]", ent)) for ent in s])
 
       key1      key2      key3
0    value1    value2    value3
1   value11   value22   value33
2  value111  value222  value333
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the series to a dictionary. use a defaultdict(list) to get all the values for a key.  the data has two delimiters: a space and a comma between each key/value pair.

```
data=pd.Series(["key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3", "key1=value11 key2=value22 key3=value33", "key1=value111,key2=value222,key3=value333"])

data_dict=defaultdict(list)
for record in data:
     my_lista=[]
     my_listb=[]
     if ',' in record:
        my_listb=record.split(',')
     else:
        my_lista=record.split()
     my_list=my_lista+my_listb
     for item in my_list:
         key,value=item.split("=")
         data_dict[key].append(value)

#a. convert the dictionary to a dataframe
data_df=pd.DataFrame(data_dict.items())
print(data_df)
```

output

```
0                            1
0  key1  [value1, value11, value111]
1  key2  [value2, value22, value222]
2  key3  [value3, value33, value333]
```